# How to group_by an annotated field for django querysets?

Tags: python, django

Hers is my model like this:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to return a queryset which is group_by created_at month, I annotated a `created_month` field for the queryset:

```py
queryset = Article.objects.annotate(created_month=TruncMonth('created_at'))
```

but when I tried to group by `created_at` by adding `.values('created_at')`, like this:

```py
queryset = Article.objects.annotate(created_month=TruncMonth('created_at')).values('created_month').order_by('-created_month')
```

The queryset returns only `created_month` field.
What shall I do to get whole Article queryset group_by `created_month` like this:

```js
[
    {
        'created_month':  '2021-07', 
        'articles': [
            {'title': 'Article 1', 'author': ...}
        ]
    },
    {
        'created_month':  '2021-06', 
        'articles': [
            {'title': 'Article 2', 'author': ...},
            {'title': 'Article 3', 'author': ...}
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do some post-processing to come up with the output format you like, as I believe none of the django APIs currently support that. But first, you need to use `values` on `created_month` as well as `title` and `author`. So something like:

```
queryset = Article.objects.annotate(
    created_month=TruncMonth('created_at')
).values('created_month', 'title', 'author').order_by('-created_month')

grouped_by_month_result = {}
for q in queryset:
     if q['created_month'] in result:
          grouped_by_month_result[q['created_month'].append(
              {'title': q['title'], 'author': q['author']}
          )
     else:
          grouped_by_month_result[q['created_month'] = [{'title': q['title'], 'author': q['author']}]

result = []
for k, v in grouped_by_month_result.items():
     result.append({
          'created_month': k,
          'articles': v,
     })
```

Comment: So I can't directly return a grouped response by one queryset sentence， right？Cause I suppose to make a paged API for it.

Comment: You still can paginate `queryset`

Comment: OK, I'll have a try. Thanks.